# Allow webserver user to unlink SFTP-uploaded files

Tags: permissions, sftp

I've set up SFTP, so that some users can upload files to a directory where the web application can pick them up. The webserver is running as user `A`, and SFTP is configured for user `B`.

User `A` is uploading files to `/sftpchroots/filesbyA/` (owned by `root:root`, to enable a chroot). Naturally, these files are owned by `A` after uploading. User `B` has to process them, though, and needs ownership to be able to remove them afterwards.

Is there a way to set it up so that everything uploaded to that directory, (or everything uploaded by user `A`) has its ownership changed to user `B`? Or is there a way to allow `B` to unlink the files without being owner (e.g. having group permissions set somehow)?

EDIT: as it turns out, the situation is a bit more nuanced. User `A` will be uploading folders with files in them. These folders will thus be owned by `A`, as well as their contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only write permission on the containing directory is needed to delete a file. Neither ownership nor permissions of the file itself come into play.

EDIT:
In the case of subdirectories being created via SFTP, this can be achieved in several ways:

- by making them world writeable (normally not desirable for security reasons)
- by making them group writeable and adding B to the group
- by adding an ACL granting B write permission

Comment: This works to some extend in the sense that it allows `B` to delete all files directly below the directory that is owned by `B`. However, as soon as `A` uploads a directory with files inside `B` cannot touch these files, it seems..

Comment: My statement applies, mutatis mutandis, to subdirectories too. B doesn't need ownership of the subdirectories, just write permission.

Comment: Right, the write permission on the child directory was missing. You're correct! Still, I've gone with ACL (with a default setting) in the end – if I understand it correctly, this prevents SFTP users from (accidently) adjusting permissions such that B cannot remove the files anymore (740?).

Comment: Absolutely. A default ACL is a good way to grant write permission to the entire directory tree.